# Markdown not aligning tables

Tags: emacs, markdown

I run markdown-mode on emacs on OSX as well and it handles tables very well. Every time I hit enter or tab, emacs fills in all the blank spaces to line up the columns.

On my ubuntu box, it doesn't seem to recognize the table at all, but the same tables work great in org-mode

I'm running markdown-mode v2.3 from MELPA-stable and I tried removing it and adding it again with no luck.

I would appreciate any suggestions as this really makes my life easier.

Comment: Are you using `orgtbl-mode` on your OSX machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded my version of markdown-mode from melpa-stable to melpa.

I also commented out this line on my emacs dot file.

```
 ;; '(package-selected-packages
 ;;  (quote
 ;;  (pkg-info haskell-mode epl edit-indirect dash markdown-mode+ ess flycheck markdown-mode ## org)))
```

I think this was some how overwriting my newer version. I don't fully understand my solution, but it works now. Hope this helps someone else.